# What's the difference between sim shalom and shalom rav?

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz

What's the difference between sim shalom and shalom rav? Why replace sim shalom at mincha and maariv?

Comment: not linked to mincha when they with kriath hatorah?

Comment: It seems from your question that you are talking about Nusach Ashkenaz. But, please edit that in, since Nusach Sfard says Sim Shalom during mincha too. There is something on Beurei Hatefilah on this topic, I believe, but I think they discuss only Nusach Ashkenaz on this topic.

Comment: Maybe we replaced _Shalom rav_ at _shacharis_?

Comment: @msh210 please indicate in an answer if that is the case and why

Comment: I believe the Igros Moshe rules that if one mistakenly began (e.g. "Shalom" instead of "Sim") the wrong version, he should continue it rather than go back, since the distinction is not mentioned in the Talmud.

Comment: Very much related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66166/origins-of-shalom-rav

Answer (score 6):

According to http://www.aishdas.org/asp/shalom-rav it is partly based on Nusach Bavel vs Nusach Eretz Yisrael

> Two variants of Shalom Rav were found in the Cairo Geniza. Given the
>   similarities between Cairo and Israeli nusachos, it is assumed to have
>   been the Nusach Eretz Yisrael in the days of the tannaim and Israeli
>   amora’im. Another indication is that Nusach Provence, the berakhah was
>   always “Shalom Rav“. The Provencial community, which was a true center
>   of Jewish Life and Torah in the days of the rishonim, had a strong
>   tradition of being refugees from the Roman conquest of Israel. In
>   fact, the Jews of Luneil had a tradition that they were descendants of
>   the city of Yericho. The name “Luneil” is from “luna” (French: moon)
>   in the same way “Yericho” would be from “yareiach” (Hebrew: moon).
>   Whether or not this tradition is historically true, it does reflect
>   the community’s roots in Israel. So it would seem Shalom Rav was the
>   Nusach Eretz Yisrael.
>
> This is one of a number of cases where Sepharadim follow Nusach Bavel
>   and Ashkenazim find a compromise between Nusach Bavel and Nusach Eretz
>   Yisrael. Among many historians, these cases are caused by the number
>   of captives from Eretz Yisrael taken back to Italy by the Roman army,
>   whose descendants then go up to Ashkenaz in Charlemagne’s day.
>
> The Provencal community ended up joining Ashkenaz. The bulk of
>   Ashkenazic Jewry, though, were invited up from Italy by Charlemagne,
>   who needed an economic backbone for the heart of the Holy Roman
>   Empire. But many of these Italian Jews were also descendents of
>   Israel; many taken back to Rome with the departing armies.
>
> Another example is the preservation of the Israeli nusach by saying it
>   in only some situations is “LeDor vaDor“, using it instead of “Atah
>   Qadosh” when saying Qedushah. In Israel (and the Cairo Geniza), LeDor
>   VaDor was simply the text of the third berakhah in every Shemoneh
>   Esrei.
>
> So it looks like splitting our time between Sim Shalom when this is a
>   tefillah in which duchaning is allowed and Shalom Rav when it is not
>   is a legacy of how Minhag Ashkenaz was formed. Descendants of Israel
>   and Bavel relocated to the same area, and had to make a common minhag
>   for this community, and so the result was a bit of compromise.
>
> This idea about the origins of Minhag and Nusach Ashkenaz (including
>   these two cases, piyut, and much more) are discussed at length in the
>   writings of Prof.s Agus and Ta-Shma, and others.

Answer (score 5):

[Kipa.co.il](http://www.kipa.co.il/ask/show/35753-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9D)  links שים שָׁלום to the priestly blessing according to [Orach Chayim 127 (2)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=301), so whenever there is a possibility for the  priestly blessing,  שים שלום is said.
The trouble there is that there is no  priestly blessing to Shabbos mincha and there is a minhag to say שים שלום (and another to say שָׁלום רָב).  Kipa.co.il links the שים שלום minhag on Shabbos mincha to the mention of  תּורַת חַיִּים in  שים שלום.

(Text of both below)

I have heard the explanation the other way round too.
שים שָׁלום contains the words  תּורַת חַיִּים and became the choice for shacharis and all other occasions when there is a reading from the Torah (e.g. a fast day at mincha).

שָׁלום רָב does not contain a reference to Torah and is used when there is no reading from the Torah.

The only snag is that some versions of Nusach Ashkenaz say  שים שָׁלום on Shabbos mincha even though there is a  reading from the Torah.

שים שָׁלום טובָה וּבְרָכָה. חֵן וָחֶסֶד וְרַחֲמִים עָלֵינוּ וְעַל כָּל יִשרָאֵל עַמֶּךָ. בָּרְכֵנוּ אָבִינוּ כֻּלָּנוּ כְּאֶחָד בְּאור פָּנֶיךָ. כִּי בְאור פָּנֶיךָ נָתַתָּ לָּנוּ ה' אֱלהֵינוּ תּורַת חַיִּים וְאַהֲבַת חֶסֶד. וּצְדָקָה וּבְרָכָה וְרַחֲמִים וְחַיִּים וְשָׁלום. וְטוב בְּעֵינֶיךָ לְבָרֵךְ אֶת כָּל עַמְּךָ יִשרָאֵל בְּכָל עֵת וּבְכָל שָׁעָה בִּשְׁלומֶךָ:

שָׁלום רָב עַל יִשרָאֵל עַמְּךָ תָּשים לְעולָם כִּי אַתָּה הוּא מֶלֶךְ אָדון לְכָל הַשָּׁלום וְטוב יִהְיֶה בְּעֵינֶיךָ לְבָרְכֵנוּ וּלְבָרֵךְ אֶת כָּל עַמְּךָ יִשרָאֵל בְּכָל עֵת וּבְכָל שָׁעָה בִּשְׁלומֶךָ.

Comment: Correct. You may also want to view page 2 of http://beureihatefila.com/files/2007-06-01Tefila_Newsletter.pdf for a slightly different explanation.